# Unable to find difference in moment js

Tags: momentjs, diff

Can someone explain me the difference between below 2 statements? I tried to print the format of both statements and ended up with the same results. I am confused :(

moment("2021-04-01T23:59:59").endOf('day')
.diff(moment("2021-03-17T23:59:59").endOf('month'), 'days');  // returning 1

and

moment("2021-04-01T23:59:59")
.diff(moment("2021-03-17T23:59:59").endOf('month'), 'days') // returning 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

```
start_1 = moment("2021-04-01T23:59:59").endOf('day')
console.log(start_1.millisecond()) // 999

start_2 = moment("2021-04-01T23:59:59")
console.log(start_2.millisecond()) // 000

end = moment("2021-03-17T23:59:59").endOf('month')

console.log(start_1.diff(end, 'days')) // 1
console.log(start_1.diff(end, 'millisecond')) // 86400000 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

console.log(start_2.diff(end, 'days')) // 0
console.log(start_2.diff(end, 'hours')) // 23
console.log(start_2.diff(end, 'millisecond')) // 86399001
```